# is it possible only get writable fields from schema.sobjectfield

Tags: apex, permissions, sobjectfield, describes

I have this code:

```
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = 
    Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(Account).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

It gets all the fields of account but I need only editable fields. I don't want read-only fields like `CreatedById`, `LastModifiedById`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get only editable fields using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`. You need additional check.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
List<String> editableFields = new List<String>();
for(Schema.SObjectField fieldRef : fields.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = fieldRef.getDescribe();
    if(fieldResult.isUpdateable()) {
        editableFields.add(fieldResult.getname());
    }
}
```

`editableFields` list will contain API names of all the editable fields.

Comment: fieldResult.isUpdateable() is not an effective way to identify writable fields.
Run this code. 
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.SObjectType.Contract.fields.ActivatedDate;

if(dfr.isUpdateable()){
    Contract con = new Contract(ActivatedDate = System.now());
}
It results in an error because the field is not writable.